# .append de Jquery me pierde las lineas y sale todo seguido

Tags: html, jquery, json

Veréis, tengo un JSON con muchos registros y quiero mostrarlo en una página web. Para añadirlo a un  de HTML uso .append() de Jquery.

Funciona bien, me añade todos los registros y me coge bien los estilos y todo, pero veo un comportamiento que no sé resolver.

Cuando recupero del JSON un texto con varios párrafos, en HTML me sale todo seguido, sin líneas nuevas. Cuando inspecciono el párrafo, en la consola se ven las líneas bien.

El trozo de código es el siguiente:

```
success: function(json){
    var datos = JSON.parse(json);
    for(var i in datos) {
    $("#resultados").append('<div class="cuadro"> \
         <p><span class="negrita">Consulta</p> \
         <p>'+datos[i].pregunta+'</p> \
         <p class="negrita">Respuesta</p> \
         <p>'+ datos[i].respuesta+'</p></div>');
  }                 
},
```

¿Le tengo que pasar alguna función a datos[i] para que me salgan las líneas?

Comment: Buenas, tienes que tener en cuenta que tal vez el texto del JSON contenga "\n" para mostrar esos saltos de línea cosa que no vale para Html. Por lo que tendrías que reemplazarlo por un br

Comment: ¿Y sabes como comprobar eso? Voy a buscar más información de eso que me dices.

Comment: Así de primeras te diría que pruebes datos[i].respuesta.replace("\n", "<br>") si te funciona prueba datos[i].respuesta.replace(/\n/g, "<br>") este ultimo es para cambiar todos los "\n"

Comment: Sí, he estado probado con \n y con \n\n. Me mete saltos nuevos y queda mejor formateado, pero no todos los saltos. ¿Sabes que caracteres se escapan aparte de \n, por ejemplo de un tabular?

Comment: Puede que también necesites interpretar los retornos de carro (return), es decir, las siguientes combinaciones: `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n` y `\n\r`. Prueba y nos comentas.

Comment: Puedes probar con "\r" que es un return y si hace falta aunque no creo con "\t" que es para tabular

Comment: He estado haciendo pruebas y he revisado los resultados que me salen , y solo me interpreta las dobles líneas, y por muchos <br /> que pongo solo me mete un <br />. Seguiré mirando a ver que pasa.

Comment: Muestra el código de cómo estás reemplazando el texto y ver si se puede cambiar algo

Comment: respuesta = datos[i].respuesta;  
respuesta = respuesta.replace("\n","<br /><br />");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te lo pongo como respuesta para que no se pierda en los comentarios.

Lo que tendrías que hacer es:

```
respuesta = datos[i].respuesta; 
respuesta = respuesta.replace(/\n/g,"<br /><br />");
```

En javascript si haces uso del replace tal que así:

```
respuesta = respuesta.replace("\n","<br /><br />")
```

Solo reemplaza la primera aparición, es por eso que hay que añadir /"Texto a cambiar"/g, ya que con esto indicamos que queremos que capture todos los "\n" y los reemplace.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Madre mía, me estaba volviendo loco con combinaciones. 

Es exactamente lo que ha funcionado, pero he cambiado los dos <br /> por uno solo para que se vea perfecto.

¡Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda!

Comment: De nada si te ha servido marca como respuesta por si sirve a alguien más. Me alegra que te sirviera.

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilitzar `<br>` para hacer saltos de línea en html.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
success: function(json){
    var datos = JSON.parse(json);
    for(var i in datos) {
    $("#resultados").append('<div class="cuadro"><br>
         <p><span class="negrita">Consulta</p><br>
         <p>'+datos[i].pregunta+'</p><br>
         <p class="negrita">Respuesta</p><br>
         <p>'+ datos[i].respuesta+'</p></div>');
  }                 
},
```

> El elemento HTML line break 
>  produce un salto de línea en el texto
>   (retorno de carro). Es útil para escribir un poema o una dirección,
>   donde la división de las líneas es significante.

[Documentación.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/br)

Comment: No es meter una línea entre párrafos, es interpretar las líneas dentro de datos[i]